# My loops are not looping

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
enter code here
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double employeeNum    = 0.0;            double totalEmployees    = 0.0;
    double hourlyRate    = 0.0;            double totalhoursWork    = 0.0;
    double hoursWork    = 0.0;            double totalnetPay        = 0.0;
    double grossPay        = 0.0;            double averagehoursWork    = 0.0;
    double netPay        = 0.0;            double totalwithHoldings = 0.0;
    double withHoldings    = 0.0;


    cout <<" Enter Employee Number or 9999 to Stop:";
    cin >> employeeNum;
    cout <<"Enter hourly rate:";
    cin >> hourlyRate;
    cout <<"Enter hours worked:";
    cin >> hoursWork;

    while(employeeNum != 9999)
    {

        if (hoursWork >= 40)
        {
            grossPay= hoursWork * hourlyRate;
            cout <<" Gross Weekly Pay:" << grossPay << endl;
        }
        else (hoursWork > 40);
        {
            grossPay= hoursWork * hourlyRate*1.5;
            cout <<" Gross Weekly Pay:" << grossPay << endl;
        }

        while( grossPay > 1,000.00)
        {
            withHoldings= grossPay/ 0.28;

        }
        while( grossPay < 1,000.0)
        {
            withHoldings= grossPay/ 0.21;
        }

        netPay= grossPay-withHoldings;
        cout <<" Net Weekly Pay:" << netPay << endl;

        cout <<" Enter Employee Number or 9999 to Stop:";
        cin >> employeeNum;
        cout <<"Enter hourly rate:";
        cin >> hourlyRate;
        cout <<"Enter hours worked:";
        cin >> hoursWork; 
    }   
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Starting with a blank solution, write a program to prompt the user for an employee number, hourly rate and hours worked. Compute and display the employee number, gross weekly pay and net weekly pay. Gross weekly pay is calculated as hours worked times rate for the first 40 hours, plus hours times 1.5 the rate for any hours over 40. Net pay is gross minus withholdings. Withholdings is calculated as 28 percent of gross pay if gross pay is over $1,000, 21 percent of gross pay if gross pay is $1000 or less. All input from the user should be verified as valid. Hourly rate must be greater than $7.25 and less than $100.00. Hours worked must be greater than 0 and less than 120. If the user enters invalid data display and appropriate error message and ask the user to re-enter. Use a post test loop to repeat this process until the user enters 9999 the program should display a total number of employees entered, total hours worked, average hours worked, total net pay and total withholdings. All numeric output should display in fixed notation with two decimal places

Comment: Homework I think. Doing debugging is a good talent for a software engineer.

Comment: @EdHeal +1, it's an absolutely essential skill.

Comment: @MartinJames - I concur but did not wish to be blunt.

Comment: You loops are quite loopy in fact. While loops may not exit because check variable is not modified inside the loop

Answer (score 3):

```
while( grossPay > 1000.00)
        {
            withHoldings= grossPay/ 0.28;

        }
```

Either the condition is true, then is stays true and the loop will loop forever, or it isn't, and the statement is never executed.

Change `while` to `if` or modify `grossPay` inside the loop.

Also, don't include a comma in a floating point constant.

Comment: so I should use the if statement

Comment: When I CHANGE It says this 1>e:\finalexamc++\finalexamc++\marquiswatkinsfinalexam.cpp(35): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
1>e:\finalexamc++\finalexamc++\marquiswatkinsfinalexam.cpp(37): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'grossPay'
1>e:\finalexamc++\finalexamc++\marquiswatkinsfinalexam.cpp(48): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'withHoldings'
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 1):

Your loops are not executing because you have a ',' in your floating point constant. use 1000.00 instead of 1,000.00

Answer (score 0):

You have the second condition duplicating the first one (`(hoursWork > 40);`) and there is a semicolon at the end of the condition.  Please check the syntax carefully before posting here.

Comment: 1>e:\finalexamc++\finalexamc++\marquiswatkinsfinalexam.cpp(35): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
1>e:\finalexamc++\finalexamc++\marquiswatkinsfinalexam.cpp(37): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'grossPay'
1>e:\finalexamc++\finalexamc++\marquiswatkinsfinalexam.cpp(48): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'withHoldings'
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
this what it says when I fixed my errors

Comment: Is it me or the notion that this is for the final exam and this person resorts to a MB to get an answer is a bit worrying. Lets hope he is not sat next to me.